# Meaning of "bringing on the necessary support"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What does "bring on" mean in the following?

> Food alone costs $2,000 per day, per person, in space. Getting provisions to and from the space station for a commercial crew is another $88,000 to $164,000 per person, per day. For each mission, **bringing on** the necessary support from NASA astronauts will cost commercial customers another $5.2 million, and all the mission support and planning that NASA lends is another $4.8 million.

Is "on" optional? Does it simply mean "on board"?

Answer (score 0):

The Merriam dictionary states "bring on" means

> transitive verb : to cause to appear or occur

In this context, it shows how commercial customers have to pay another $5.2 million for the [*unintentional*/not a **must**] support by NASA astronauts. Think of it like this

> Support by NASA astronauts = extra $5.2 million

"bring on" in M-W is used with unintentional (and mostly undesirable) things - @Apollyon

Comment: "bring on" in M-W is used with unintentional (and mostly undesirable) things.

Comment: @Apollyon I have changed my answer slightly

Comment: in the UK "bring it on" is a phrase said to show that you are prepared and willing to compete in a competition or to do something difficult "is that all you have bring it on"